# Getting a process ID by clicking on the window of an app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm developing a project using MVC 3, and I'm trying to get some process selection functionality going. I already have a select which lists all running processes in a nice drop down format, but I want to take it one step further.

As it stands, a user uses a dropdown menu to select a process from a list of all processes running, and that information gets passed to the view. I'm trying to figure out how to allow the user to click on an icon in the view, then click on a currently open window to pass that window's process ID to the view.

So far all I have is a click event set up for the `<img>`. I've hit a total roadblock as to what to do next. There's a lot of information on getting a list of all processes, but not a whole lot on getting a specific process via a mouse click. Any thoughts would be helpful.

As far as I can figure, I'll have to wire up a click event in jQuery which fires off a C# action. This action then waits for the user to click a window, grabs that window's process ID, and then sends it back to the view.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is this a web page that shows the processes running on a user's machine? Or on the server itself?

Comment: if question is related to client side, provide some example html with explanation that relates to the html ... as currently stands question is bouncing all over the globe

Comment: I guess my question is a little vague. I'm working on a web application. I have two project solutions. One is the web part of it, where the Views are contained. The other is a client which a user would run on their machine. Basically, a user runs the client, and the data from the web portion gets sent to that client to generate views and so forth. I'm editing the web portion now, and what I'm stuck on is how to click an icon, be able to select a window, have that window's process ID get sent back (and probably have the previously mentioned dropdown catch the ID and auto select the process).

Answer (score 0):

I am confused, web page how to obtain the user's computer have to process it?
Browser has its own safe behavior, and can directly manipulate the user's computer is not safe?

You can use the browser plug-in function to obtain the user's computer process

In addition, I see you You say you have a client on the client computer
So you can get the user clicks through the client what is the process, and then communicated by the client to the server, and then show the form to the browser using server push